# How to disambiguate PostgreSQL column references from table references in projections?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assuming I have a schema like this:

```sql
create table x (t1 int, t2 int);
create table t1 (t1 int, t2 int);
insert into x values (1, 2);
insert into t1 values (1, 2);
```

Now in PostgreSQL, I can conveniently project table references to create nested rows in the result:

```sql
select x from x;
```

Producing:

```
|x     |
|------|
|[1, 2]|
```

But this doesn't work if there's a conflict between tables and columns:

```sql
select t1 from t1;
```

That just translates to an unqualified column reference:

```
|t1 |
|---|
|1  |
```

Now, as I'm maintaining a SQL generator, let's assume I cannot alias the table (because I might not know what column names it contains, and any alias could still conflict with actual columns).

Is there any syntax which allows for disambiguating between table reference and column reference, such as e.g. a hypothetical syntax below?

```sql
select t1::the_table_not_the_column from t1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work, if I know the column names:

```sql
select row(t1, t2)::t1 as t1 from t1
```

Or, if I don't know the column names:

```sql
select row(t1.*)::t1 as t1 from t1
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose to simply use *table aliases* in these situations:

```
SELECT t FROM x AS t
```

Done.

Comment: Have you read the fine print of my question? *"Now, as I'm maintaining a SQL generator, let's assume I cannot alias the table"*

Comment: I haven't, Lukas.  Apologies.

Comment: No worries. Someone else might still find this approach useful, as it's unlikely this won't work for them...